# tabularray: justified text instead of ragged alignment

Tags: tables, justification, tabularray

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Verdana}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{p{7.5cm}}
\textbf{UN 3264} Abfall ätzender saurer anorganischer flüssiger Stoff, n.a.g. (Schwefelsäure, Eisensulfat-Lösung), 8, II, (E), umweltgefährdend
\end{tblr}
\\
\begin{tabular}{p{7.5cm}}
\textbf{UN 3264} Abfall ätzender saurer anorganischer flüssiger Stoff, n.a.g. (Schwefelsäure, Eisensulfat-Lösung), 8, II, (E), umweltgefährdend  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I couldn't figure out why the `p` column type produces ragged alignment for the `tblr` environment, but justified text alignment when the `tabular` environment is used. How can I achieve justified text for `tblr`?

Comment: `\begin{tblr}{Q[j,7.5cm]}` should result in the expected justified output.

Comment: That @leandriis suggestion will work you should have installed recent version of `tabularray` package (2021P).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @leandriis! Do you want to cast your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabularray` offers the `Q` column type. It accepts vertical and horizontal alignment options, as well as a specified width. For a table column with justified text and a certain width, we can thus use `Q[j,7.5cm]`.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Verdana}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tblr}{Q[j,7.5cm]}
\textbf{UN 3264} Abfall ätzender saurer anorganischer flüssiger Stoff, n.a.g. (Schwefelsäure, Eisensulfat-Lösung), 8, II, (E), umweltgefährdend
\end{tblr}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{7.5cm}}
\textbf{UN 3264} Abfall ätzender saurer anorganischer flüssiger Stoff, n.a.g. (Schwefelsäure, Eisensulfat-Lösung), 8, II, (E), umweltgefährdend  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```